# How Middleware class receives parameters in Asp.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

this is my first question so please do not judge strictly

I'm trying to understand how **Middleware** receives parameters from **Configure** method in **Startup** class.

Here is the code of **Middleware** class:

```
public class LocationMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate next;
    private MessageOptions options;

    public LocationMiddleware(RequestDelegate nextDelegate,IOptions<MessageOptions> opts)
    {
        next = nextDelegate;
        options = opts.Value;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path=="/location")
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{options.CityName}, {options.CountryName}");
        }
        else
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Constructor of this class takes 2 parameters `RequestDelegate` and `IOptions<MessageOptions>`
But when calling a method `UseMiddleware` in `Startup` class no parameters are being sent in this line `app.UseMiddleware<LocationMiddleware>();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMiddleware<LocationMiddleware>();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    }
```

So my question is how middleware class receives this parameters?

Answer (score 0):

> Constructor of this class takes 2 parameters `RequestDelegate` and `IOptions<MessageOptions>` But when calling a method `UseMiddleware` in `Startup` class no parameters are being sent in this line `app.UseMiddleware<LocationMiddleware>();`

I assume that you added/registered `MessageOptions` to the service container, which will be resolved in your custom middleware.

```
services.Configure<MessageOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MessageOptions"));
```

Besides, you can check [the source code of `UseMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f37fa30683a92d83297434103a43b3d46aaa93a9/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs#L90) to know how it works.